# Detect audio clipping in RTMP live stream using Python

Tags: python, audio-streaming, audio-analysis

I have a live RTMP audio/video stream which I want to analyse for clipping in the audio stream. The audio is encoded using either OGG, MP3 or AAC. Any thoughts on how I can do this, or what Python library I can use for this? Many thanks in advance.

-EDIT- by clipping I mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(signal_processing)

Answer (score 0):

By "clipping the audio stream", do you mean drops in audio quality, like the muffling of the microphone, or something else? This library would likely work for general audio analysis: https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis. From there you could detect dropoffs in volume and quality as a sign of clipping

Comment: Yes indeed. I want to detect when the input signal is too strong so that the signal is distorted.